# The state of not knowing and/or ignoring each other

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a word that expresses the state of not knowing and/or ignoring each other.

In a blog post, I've found the term *Principle of Mutual Oblivion*. This is supposed to be a rule in software engineering that states that two things should not know each other (to be more precise: Two modules at the same level of abstraction should not know each other).

The word *oblivion* feels strange to me here. I know two meanings of the word *oblivion*:

1. the state of no longer being known (to sink/fall into oblivion)
2. to be unconscious, sleeping, or otherwise unaware of everything around (to drink oneself into oblivion).

Wiktionary, MacMillan, and Merriam-Webster support this.

Can *oblivion* be the noun that precisely corresponds to *to be oblivious to something* (in the sense of completely ignoring or not knowing something specific)? It seems to me that it is meant in that way here.

If oblivion is not the right word in that context, what's a better word? In the concrete case, it doesn't matter if the word expresses willingly ignoring something specific or the lack of knowledge of something specific. But it should not express being completely unaware of everything. It should also be a neutral term. I came up with ignorance, i.e., *Principle of Mutual Ignorance*. Is that better?

Comment: If you are willingly ignorant of something, you are still aware of its existence. Would something like **isolated** fit?

Comment: I'd say 'unawareness' but you haven't given much context.

Comment: A clue:  relatively few inventors of words for features in the world computing and programming worry too much about sticking to precise meanings. You could call it ‘modular isolation’, ‘modular insulation’, or anything that roughly fits the bill.

Comment: The term already exists somehow. So I just wonder if the word "oblivion" is used correctly here. "Unawareness" would fit. Isolation would have a slightly different semantics.

Comment: Can it be 'unintroduced'?

Comment: Sounds like some blogger just discovered something that’s been known about for sixty years, and wanted to give it an edgy name. The generally accepted name for this principle of software design is “Separation of Concerns”.

Comment: Merriam-Webster has for [oblivion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivion) "the condition or state of being forgotten or unknown". This "mutual oblivion" seems to mean A doesn't know B and B doesn't know A, so it would fit.

Answer (score -1):

As an IT engineer myself, I know what you are talking about.

I believe the word you are looking for is **seclusion**.

Comment: Can you provide a dictionary definition or any other reference to support this,  or maybe an example of somebody (other than you) using this word in this context?

Comment: Can seclusion be mutual? I'd like to express that neither A knows B nor vice versa. But they both should depend on a C on a lower level of abstraction. Seclusion feels to me more like "closed against certain types of changes". Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

**Willful ignorance,** an idiom, may be useful for your question.  [YFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ignorance)

> An intentional obliviousness to something that one knows to be true.

As in:

> Your willful ignorance is appalling!.